# Is using placeholder (blank) views for spacing reasons considered bad form?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uikit

Specifically, I am using `UIStackView` and Auto Layout to position subviews within a modal sheet.

I am having trouble positioning my subviews such that are laid out nicely and adaptively across various screen sizes/orientations.

Potential solutions:

- `UITraitCollection` cannot be used because for different iPhone screen sizes, they are of the same size class
- Also cannot use static `layoutMargins` insets because this is not adaptive

Question: I think I would be able to effectively manipulate the spacing within the `UIStackView` by adding intermediary placeholder views and setting their height/width constraints in Auto Layout. But is this not a good solution? If not, what is generally the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [`setCustomSpacing(_:after:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/2866023-setcustomspacing)?

Comment: @Sweeper I did come across that, but it does not really fit my use case. I need something more adaptive than just static spacing values (`CGFloat`)

Comment: There is virtually no problem that has just one solution. I have used spacing views when appropriate, IMHO perfectly reasonable. My $0.02.

Comment: @ennell - Abstract questions are very difficult to answer. Show us a real example of what you're trying to do, and point out what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific scenario, if you're not dealing with a huge number of subviews, using intermediary views inside StackView could be a quick and effective solution. However, if you anticipate needing more complex or adaptive layouts in the future, it might be worth investing the time to develop a more scalable, programmatically controlled layout system.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    if screenWidth > 375 { // iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone X, etc.
        myStackView.spacing = 20
    } else {
        myStackView.spacing = 10
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer to use Auto layout for it, using DSL. For example SnapKit

You can either updateConstraints or remakeConstraints on different type of scenarios

```
// Create a UIView and add it to the parent view
let myView = UIView()
parentView.addSubview(myView)

// Use SnapKit to set constraints
myView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
    make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
}

// Update padding based on screen size
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    myView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset((screenWidth > 375) ? 30 : 20)
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset((screenWidth > 375) ? -30 : -20)
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Because UIScreen.main is actually deprecated, you can use this extension helper to get access to the screenSize

```
import UIKit

public extension UIApplication {
    var mainWindow: UIWindow? {
        return UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .compactMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow }
            .first
    }
    
    var screenSize: CGSize? {
        return mainWindow?.frame.size
    }
    
    var screenWidth: CGFloat? {
        return screenSize?.width
    }
}
```

You can then get the screen width in your code like this:

```
if let width = UIApplication.shared.screenWidth {
    print("Screen Width: \(width)")
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but in my `UIViewController` managing the `UIStackView`, I don't have access to the `UIWindowScene.screen` as per [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3198089-screen?language=objc). Furthermore, `UIScreen.main` is deprecated.